# Sails.js SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Tags: controller, sails.js, helper

I am very new to Sails.js, but a client wants me to create a master controller that calls all of the helper functions. Here is an example:

```
result = await sails.helpers.user.action(action, req, result);
```

```
module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'User Action',


  description: 'User Action tile.',


  inputs: {
    action: {
        description: 'action of grid',
        required: true,
        type: "string",
      },
      req: {
          description: 'req object posted',
          required: true,
          type: "ref",
      },
      result: {
          description: 'req object posted',
          type: "ref",
          defaultsTo: {},
      },
  },


  exits: {

    success: {
      description: 'All done.',
    },

  },


  fn: async function (inputs) {
    var action = inputs.action;
    var req = inputs.req;
    var result = inputs.result;
    var post = inputs.req;
    user_id = req.me ? req.me.user_id : 0;
```

When I run the code, I get the error mentioned in the title. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error refer to: Your function must be an async function to use 'wait', just put async keyword before function definition, like that.

```
    async function doSomething() {
        result = await sails.helpers.user.action(action, req, result);
    }
```

Comment: I actually figured this out by working with my partner, but I appreciate the help. Thank you.